# Using Rails with no models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, configuration

I have an application that utilizes web service calls from the controller to attain its data. I have no models and don't need them (the app just reads and displays data). However, when the app is deployed I get an ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished error. How or Can I configure Rails to ignore ActiveRecord functionality, basically ignore anything that's associated with databases or models?

I'm using Rails 4. Thanks.

Comment: can you check if you have this line require "active_record/railtie" in your config/application.rb file? You have to comment it out if its there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that your `config/application.rb` doesn't have require `'rails/all'` or `require "active_record/railtie"`. Instead, for a standard Rails setup without ActiveRecord, it should have only the following requires:

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
require "rails/test_unit/railtie"
require "sprockets/railtie"
```

Comment: Getting this "`require': cannot load such file -- active_resource/railtie"

Comment: well, activeresource has been pulled off from rails 4 so please comments out the line that says require "active_resource/railtie"

Comment: Just in case if you think that you need to use activeresource then you gotta add it as a gem in your gemfile since it has been extracted as a gem for rails 4 http://rubygems.org/gems/activeresource

Comment: Wondering if that resource is still in `rails/all` since it appears not to be in [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/initialization.html) section 2.1. The point of your answer, that is to only require parts of Rails that I actually am using, did forge the way to the solution, so thanks.